# NAudio alternative for C++

Tags: c++, audio

I am long time programming with C# and NAuido, now i moved to modern C++. I am has a few projects for audio visualization: Waveform, spectrum analyzer, etc. Now i going to port my projects for C++, but the problem is that for C ++ there are a huge number of different audio libraries with different functional.

My minimum requirements for the proposed candidate:

1. Full Support for working with digital audio(.wav, .mp3 .flac) and API for acces to audio samples.
2. Permissive software license(MIT or analogs).
3. Good documentation, with samples.
4. Cross Platform(Windows, Linux).